# How to add class to paragraph fields through preprocess hook?

Tags: hooks, 9, paragraphs

I created a paragraph named flight-search-info-block with two fields: `field_svg_icon` and `field_teaser_text`. Then I created a custom block, where that paragraph was added as an entity reference field. Now I want the structure as

```
<div class="item-wrap">
  <div class="item-img">...field_svg_img....</div>
  <div class="item-text">...field_teaser_text....</div>
<div>
```

I want to do this using `hook_preprocess_paragraph`. With this hook I was able to add the class to the paragraph wrapper div (yellow marked in the attached image). I also tried `hook_preprocess_field`, but again the class was added to the paragraph.

[image]
[image]
[image]

So how can I add the classes to the red marked elements?

Answer (score 1):

Come from the other way. Come from the field. Check the parent entity (paragraph) type and then add the classes:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_field__MYFIELD(&$variables) {
  /** @var \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph $paragraph */
  $paragraph = $variables['element']['#object'];
  if ($paragraph->bundle() === 'foobar') {
    foreach ($variables['items'] as $delta => $item) {
      $variables['items'][$delta]['attributes']->addClass(['foo', 'bar', 'item-' . $delta]);
    }
  }
}
```